# How to align <table> in <td> with rest <td>'s

Tags: html, html-table

I have a table which has 5 columns. I have created an inner table in the 3rd column and this table has 3 columns. I would like to align this 3 columns with parent's rest 3 columns. Is that possible?

**Important note: I have to use Table in Table because I am creating this using AngularJs. I don't know the exact row counts for this table**

This is my Html

```html
<table style="width: 100%" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 20%"> Test Data 1</td>
    <td style="width: 20%"> Test Data 2</td>
    <td style="width: 20%"> Test Data 3
      <table border="1">
        <tr>
          <td style="width: 20%"> Test Data 3.1</td>
          <td style="width: 20%"> Test Data 3.2</td>
          <td style="width: 20%"> Test Data 3.3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="width: 20%"> Test Data 3.1-1</td>
          <td style="width: 20%"> Test Data 3.2-1</td>
          <td style="width: 20%"> Test Data 3.3-1</td>
        </tr>
      </table>

    </td>
    <td style="width: 20%"> Test Data 4</td>
    <td style="width: 20%"> Test Data 5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and this is the screenshot

[image]

I'd like to see

Test Data 3.1 is under Test Data 3

Test Data 3.2 is under Test Data 4

Test Data 3.3 is under Test Data 5

Comment: `I would like to align this 3 columns with parent's rest 3 columns`, please clearify.

Comment: I think this is enough for clearify: I'd like to see

Test Data 3.1 is under Test Data 3

Test Data 3.2 is under Test Data 4

Test Data 3.3 is under Test Data 5

Comment: Couldn't you just put three, one cell tables, in your bigger table? One table each under test data 3, 4, and 5

Comment: @j08691 no mate. Actually, this table is being created by an AngularJS ng-repeat code, therefore, I need to create it like my example

Comment: please add a picture or drawing for expected result.

Comment: I think the problem has nothing to do with the layout but the logic of data rendering. Could you please share your script as well?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.td {
    overflow:visible;
}
.overflow {
    margin-left:-4px;
    width: 60%;
    position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<table style="width: 100%" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 20%"> Test Data 1</td>
    <td style="width: 20%"> Test Data 2</td>
    <td style="width: 20%"> Test Data 3
      <table class="overflow">
        <tr>
          <td style="width: 33%"> Test Data 3.1</td>
          <td style="width: 33%"> Test Data 3.2</td>
          <td style="width: 33%"> Test Data 3.3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="width: 33%"> Test Data 3.1-1</td>
          <td style="width: 33%"> Test Data 3.2-1</td>
          <td style="width: 33%"> Test Data 3.3-1</td>
        </tr>
      </table>

    </td>
    <td style="width: 20%"> Test Data 4</td>
    <td style="width: 20%"> Test Data 5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I think there are three ways you could do this:

1. Simply create a second row in your main table and give the first 2 columns  `rowspan="2"`. I don't know if there's any specific reason you need to have a table within your table.
2. It will be tricky to get it to line up like you want it to, but if you set `overflow: visible;` for the cell that the table is in, and set the width of the second tables columns to 100%, it should be possible to line them up. (Note that it's 100% width because that sets it to the full width of the parent container, which is already 20% of the table width.) I've added a snippet demonstrating how this is done :)

Hopefully one of those helps you a bit :)

Comment: Mate thanks for your contribution but it is possible that there could be many rows in instead of my second table. I dynamically create these using AngularJs

Comment: The suspense is killing me

Comment: After looking into this a little, I think using rowspan might be your best option to get a nice looking result, but if you really need a table within a table, I'll see if I can get a code snippet working.

Comment: I've made a basic proof of concept of what I mean in my second point. It'll need a bit of fiddling to get perfect, but hopefully it helps you a bit :)

Answer (score 0):

use `rowspan` for first two `td`  in first `tr`

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.arr = [{ id: 1, data1: "Test Data 1", data2: "Test Data 2", data3: 'Test Data 3', data4: 'Test Data 4', data5: 'Test Data 5', rowspan: 2 },
{id: 2, data3: 'Test Data 3.1', data4: 'Test Data 3.2', data5: 'Test Data 3.3' }];
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl"> 

<table style="width: 100%" border="1">
  <tr ng-repeat="val in arr">
    <td  style="width: 20%" ng-hide="$index>0" rowspan="{{val.rowspan}}">{{ val.data1 }}</td>
    <td  style="width: 20%" ng-hide="$index>0" rowspan="{{val.rowspan}}">{{ val.data2 }}</td>
    <td  style="width: 20%">{{ val.data3 }}</td>
    <td  style="width: 20%">{{ val.data4 }}</td>
    <td  style="width: 20%">{{ val.data5 }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

**OUTPUT** 
[image]

Comment: thanks for your contribution but please see my edited question. I need to create table in the table

Comment: please add a picture or drawing for expected result

Comment: The expected result is like your result but I cannot use row span. I need two different tables because I am creating these tables dynamically

Comment: then you have to write logic in Angular itself to use `rowspan` . no need for another table.

Comment: @MareCieco i updated code with AngularJS. have a look.

Answer (score -1):

Use only one table with colspan and rowspan